# Building a formula that builds a URL with variables from cells (which will be keywords)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Google Sheets... Basically... I want to build a URL (it'll be a boolean site: search) where one cell field will be the website that is searched and another cell will be the keywords to search for. If there are more than one keywords in the field it'll need to replace the spaces with + signs in the URL.

Example is I have 'opentoexport.com' in a cell for the website and 'this is a test' in the field for the search term/keywords. It needs to build a URL that replace the spaces in the search term with + signs like this - google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:opentoexport.com+this+is+a+test.

To try to make it clearer what I mean, I want some kind of formula that would make a URL like google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:(Cell C:4)+(Cell A:4) where C:4 was the website I wanted to do a site: search of and C:4 would be keywords. The keywords in C:4 have spaces between them and the URL needs those spaces to be a + sign instead.

The formula I've tried so far is =CONCAT("google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:($C4)+($A4))") which doesn't work.

The info in C4 is 'opentoexport.com' which is the website I want to do the site search of on Google.
The info in A4 are the keywords which is the search term I want to use on Google  for the site: search, which in this instance is 'articles export market'. I want it to create https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:opentoexport.com+this+is+a+test.

Here is an example of the sheet I'm using... https://goo.gl/RHEXce

Could anyone help? It seems complicated but I'm hoping someone who knows what they're doing might be able to make it simple?

*note i've had to mess with the URLs to allow myself to post because it warned I had too many links*

Comment: Welcome on SO. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Does this formula work as you want:

`="https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:"&C4&"+"&SUBSTITUTE(A4," ","+")`

Comment: Thank you! This does the job.